# Onboard virtual keyboard error in RDP environment

Tags: keyboard, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp, onboard

When I use `onboard` command in RDP environment (Xfce), an error occurs.
Below is a message when an error occurs.
Could you help me with this error?

version : 16.04

```
**hello@gbot:~$ onboard**
14:08:37.352 WARNING OnboardGtk: vk: XkbGetKeyboard failed.
14:08:37.406 WARNING Onboard.XInput: Failed to create osk.Devices: failed to initialize XInput extension
14:08:37.406 WARNING TouchInput: XInput event source failed to initialize, falling back to GTK.
14:08:37.406 WARNING Onboard.Keyboard: XInput click simulator CSFloatingSlave unavailable, falling back to CSButtonMapper.
14:08:37.451 WARNING TouchInput: XInput event source failed to initialize, falling back to GTK.
14:08:38.902 WARNING OnboardGtk: vk: XkbGetKeyboard failed.
14:08:39.902 WARNING OnboardGtk: vk: XkbGetKeyboard failed.
```